# Automatic reboot on systemd emergency mode?

Tags: updates, systemd, boot, reboot, systemctl

Is it possible that, when systemd enters emergency mode, instead of prompting :

```
You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view
system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "exit"
to boot into default mode.
Press Enter for maintenance
(or press Control-D to continue):
```

and waiting for a user input, it automatically reboots after a delay ?

This would be needed in my case because I'm working on rollbacking the operating system to a previous state in case of a boot failure.

This would have to happen whatever the issue there is with the current operating system trying to boot. I haven't found anything about this yet, so any suggestion would be helpful!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well I've found a way to do what I wanted. I've overriden the emergency service with `systemctl edit emergency.service` and added :

```
[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c "read -t 30 || /bin/systemctl reboot"
```

which will wait for a user input to enter emergency mode. Otherwise, the system reboots.

This also works for the rescue mode, by doing `systemctl edit rescue.service`.